# Edit JSON Fields

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON coming from server as below

```
   {
    "XXXX": {
        "type": "RSS",
        "value": ""
    },
    "YYYY": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": ""
    },
    "ZZZZ": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": ""
    }
}
```

Now I need to add the `String` value in fields of all XXXX, YYYY, and ZZZZ.

I'm using eclipse and I need to change the value of "value" in XXXX and YYYY and ZZZZ and I need to add the field

```
{
    "MMMM": {
        "type": "Image",
        "value": "a7e8bec0-87ed-11e2-aa2e-52540025ab96_2_1362746556"
    }
}
```

After ZZZZ. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Can you please come with more details. What do you mean to say by change the value? Are you talking about eclipse editor?

Comment: i needto add new string values to value whicj is now ""

Comment: Where you want change the json value ? Controller side or sript side?

Comment: Do you just want to make this edit by hand, inside of your editor? You mention eclipse, but you tagged Java and Android, and JSON is the same regardless of the platform/language.  If you're doing it by hand, then just do what you've got there.  If you want to do it programmatically, then you need to explain what you're doing in which language, where, and how you're getting the JSON in the first place...

Comment: @user1340801 : plz share full json string which u are getting from server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
String jsonstring="{
    "XXXX": {
        "type": "RSS",
        "value": ""
    },
    "YYYY": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": ""
    },
    "ZZZZ": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": ""
    }
}";

JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONObject childobject=object.getJSONObject("XXXX");

JSONObject modifiedjson=new JSONObject();
modifiedjson.put("type",childobject.get("type"));
modifiedjson.put("value","newvalue");  // Add new value of XXXX here

//

JSONObject mmjson=new JSONObject();
mmjson.put("type","image");
mmjson.put("value","a7e8bec0-87ed-11e2-aa2e-52540025ab96_2_1362746556");  // Add new value of MMM here

JSONObject newjson=new JSONObject();
newjson.put("MMMM",mmjson.toString());
newjson.put("XXXX",modifiedjson.toString());
newjson.put("YYYY",object.get("YYYY"));
newjson.put("ZZZZ",object.get("ZZZZ"));
```

Comment: yeah thanks.got it...Is there any way for me to get the name at XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ i.e name representing json array node.because the name at XXXX orYYYY or ZZZZ may change every time ...???

Comment: You can get a string by index and then you can convert into a jsonobject. You don't need name there..Don't forgot to accept this as answer..

Comment: okay..but i have one doubt in the above answer..when i get the XXXX by
JSONObject childobject=object.getJSONObject("XXXX");

 and i need to change the value of XXXX field how can i do this?

Comment: @user1340801 check new json we are not assigning the old XXXX to the new json newjson.put("XXXX",modifiedjson.toString());, but we are assigning the modified json, i.e we are not using childobject at all

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant

```
{"XXXX":
{"type":"RSS","value":"},
"YYYY (mins)":{"type":"String","value":""},
"ZZZZ":{"type":"String","value":""}
```

is the JSON you get from server. You can always get the JSONObject.toString and edit it as required and then do something like,

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString);
```

If you need to add a key value to JSON you may try,

```
JSONObject value = new JSONObject();
value.put("key","value");
value.put("key","value");//add all the field you want for ZZZZ.
obj.put("ZZZZ",value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, you can just search for the specified values and concat the new string.

If it is a JSON Object, you could add new Values to the JSON Object and search for the values you want to manipulate and set them new.

What are you doing at the moment? Can you show us some code, so we know, where exactly you have the problem? And show, how you are accessing the JSON in this code, please.

Comment: i need to add a String value to the field value in json..like i need to add "hello there" to value in XXXX and YYYY and ZZZZ

Answer (score 0):

User Java String replacement method to replace string.

Take you Json as a string then replace value via string replacement method.

Here is small example.

```
String replaceSample = "This String replace Example shows how to replace one char from 

String newString = replaceSample.replace('r', 't');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var source={
                "XXXX": {
                    "type": "RSS",
                    "value": ""
                },
                "YYYY": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": ""
                },
                "ZZZZ": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": ""
                }
            }
```

And element you wanted to add

```
 var element={
        "type": "Image",
        "value": "a7e8bec0-87ed-11e2-aa2e-52540025ab96_2_1362746556"
    };
```

You can do with below script,

```
source["MMMM"]=element;
```

or

```
source.MMMM=element;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all operations in JavaScript itself.

Lets store the date coming from server into variable `a`:

```
var a = {
    "XXXX":{"type":"RSS","value":"},
    "YYYY (mins)":{"type":"String","value":""},
    "ZZZZ":{"type":"String","value":""}
}
```

To change the value:

```
a['XXXX']['value'] = 'new_value1';
a['YYYY']['value'] = 'new_value2';
a['ZZZZ']['value'] = 'new_value3';
```

To add a field:

```
a["MMMM"] = {"type":"Image","value":"a7e8bec0-87ed-11e2-aa2e-52540025ab96_2_1362746556"}}
```

Comment: i need to do in client side like on controller side not on javascript..i.e on client side