# how can i add data in to json file in java?

Tags: java, json

i want to add data inside of an existing json file..

this is my code:

```
    JsonWriterWithGui(){
        if(ae.getSource() == btn_submit){

            String lname = (String)lbl_name.getText().toString();
            String ladd = (String)lbl_add.getText().toString();
            String lcontact = (String)lbl_contact.getText().toString();

            FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter( "E:\\"+tsave+".json");

            jsonFileWriter.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
            jsonFileWriter.flush();
            jsonFileWriter.close();
```

this code is already working. but I am trying to update a json file that already exists.

Comment: When you say "add data inside of an existing json file", what do you mean?  Are you trying to append to the end of the file or edit the existing JSON data in the file?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334539/edit-json-fields

Comment: @ATG yes im trying to append to the end

Comment: So what's actually going wrong?

Comment: Read in the file, parse it into Lists and Maps, modify the List/Map "tree" appropriately, "serialize" the tree back into a JSON string (or byte array), write the string back to a file.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a guess because the problem you're having isn't entirely clear from the question, but if you're finding that your writes are overwriting instead of appending then try changing this line:

```
FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter( "E:\\"+tsave+".json");
```

...to this:

```
FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter("E:\\"+tsave+".json", true);
```

You see, `FileWriter` is backed by `FileOutputStream`, which takes a boolean argument saying whether new content should be appended or not.  This boolean is `false` by default so if you want to append then you need to explicitly say so.

Comment: It's never valid to "modify" a JSON string by simply appending to the end of it.  At the absolutely minimum very least one would have to rewrite the last byte of the original JSON.

Comment: This may be true, but all we know so far is that there's a problem appending to the end of a file so that's all the help I can offer.  I'm not making any assumptions about the nature of the data in the file already.

Comment: "i want to add data inside of an existing json file.."

Comment: That's not what the comment says, though.  Why don't you edit the question to make it clear if you're so sure you understand what the problem is?

Comment: Which comment?  The OP has only said "yes im trying to append to the end".  But a) he clearly doesn't know what he's doing, and b) he doesn't indicate that he wants to append to the end of the *file* vs to the end of the *existing JSON*.  You told him to do something stupid and useless -- did not advance his knowledge at all.

Comment: I dunno about that, at least he/she knows how to append to files now.  Again, I'd be happy to improve my answer if it were clearer what the real problem was.