# How to read nested JSON objects in spring-boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, rest

I have a below JSON response from one of the RESP API, created in spring-boot, I want to know that how can I read this JSON file and add, one more attribute to it, let's say **"PID" = 4321**. as I am consuming this API using restTemplate in spring boot, and I want to store the updated JSON file to my database i.e. response of (REST API + PID) as mentioned.

Below is the JSON response I am getting:

```
[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vishal",
        "age": 22,
        "emailId": "VISL@VISHAL.COM"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Vishal2",
        "age": 26,
        "emailId": "VISHAL1@VISHA1L.COM"
    }

]
```

Thanks in Advance, for anyone's help or guidance

Comment: what is you question/problem? And what have you tried. Show us your java code

Comment: You could use JSONObject, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334539/edit-json-fields

Comment: If you're storing your information in your app by POJO, you can use **fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-databind** `ObjectMapper` to parse JSON string to a POJO.